# How can I subdivide the first column in the Bootstrap 2 grid?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have something like this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span1"> Nr </div>
    <div class="span11"> Text </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the first column takes up 8.3% of the row width, but I only want it to take up 5% of the width - with the entire remaining portion of 95% being used for the second column.

How would you subdivide the first column and then add its remaining part to the second column?

Comment: That's a fairly heavy-handed approach. You don't normally want to mess with your grid columns. Can you maybe right-align the first column's content to achieve the same result?

Comment: @isherwood. Thank you. Yes I can do that, but I'm trying to use html in printouts - so I need the ability to use finer measurements. Another problem is that if you use a larger screen (+32 inches), then wasting an entire span on one field looks really stupid.

Comment: Well, if you're using a container the page never gets crazy wide. Here's what that might look like. I used `span2` to better illustrate the technique. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/g97g16cw/

Comment: Ya, it looks okay if you use the last column - as you did, but using the first column without wasting space looks like bumping your head.

Comment: I also tried a container with a row-fluid inside. In the row-fluid I have a table, which can handle percentages for column widths. But the row-fluid cannot contain the table if you increase its left margin - resulting in the table extending off the page.

Comment: What scaffolding system would give you granular control (using percentages in column widths) while still being responsive? Looks like Bootstrap 4 is sticking to 12 columns - but maybe their move to Sass could make a difference.

Comment: Since Bootstrap 2 you could customize column count, though the version 2 customizer is deprecated. You'd do a 20-column grid. http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media(min-width: 768px) {
    .span1.five {
        width: 5%;
        background: pink;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .span1.five + div {
        width: 92%; /* << could be refined to get closer to the page margin */
    }
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/g97g16cw/5/)**

You'd want to [nest a row](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem) inside the `span11` element to break it up further.

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/g97g16cw/6/)**

Comment: The columns in those demo's do not display inline - or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you looking at it large enough? I didn't override the mobile (full-width) styling for widths under 768px, as you can see.

Comment: Oops, my mistake, had to drag the column wider. So you are basically overriding the Bootstrap widths? Looks like the best option, since it is still responsive. Many thanx.